# TSLint Error: Argument of type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration' is not assign able to parameter of type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration'

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

Unable to Build my SharePoint solution.
When building, each of my webparts has the error

```
"Argument of type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration' is not assign able to parameter of type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration'."
```

all my sharepoint module imports are the same in all webparts:

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { Version, Environment, EnvironmentType } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
   BaseClientSideWebPart,
   IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
   PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
```

Package,json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.3.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-http": "^1.3.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.3.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "sp-client-custom-fields": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.3.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.3.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.3.0",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9"
  }
```

Tried removing node_modules and installing a few times and still experiencing the same issue.

Also Removed both sp-http and sp-client-custom-fields.
and now I am getting the error.

```
Cannot find module '@microsoft/sp-http'
```

Already posted an issue on github and wanted to see if anyone else has experienced this problem

Heres the reported issue:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/911

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the method that you are using to consume the `SPHttpClient` ?

Comment: in a request to a sharepoint list.

  private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient
      .get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
  `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('${this.sharepointLists[this.properties.SharepointList] ? this.sharepointLists[this.properties.SharepointList].Title : 'DataAnalytics'}')/items?$orderby=csd_order asc`,
      **SPHttpClient.configurations.v1**)
      .then((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
      });
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your import statement as below (probably not needed to modify your import statement but adding it for safer side):

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientConfiguration, SPHttpClientResponse, 
ISPHttpClientConfiguration } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

And change your method as below. You need to change `Response` to `SPHttpClientResponse`. This is the correct way as the response will be in the type `SPHttpClientResponse`. JSON data will then be extracted from the response using the methods available.

```
private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> { 

    var queryUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('${this.sharepointLists[this.prop‌​erties.SharepointLis‌​t] ? this.sharepointLists[this.properties.SharepointList].Title : 'DataAnalytics'}')/items?$orderby=csd_order asc";

    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(queryUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
               .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
                        return response.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: I copied the node_modules folder from a clean generation of spfx and was unable to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still stuggling with this issue, the resolution for me was as follows:

```
npm uninstall @microsoft/sp-http

npm uninstall @microsoft/sp-application-base

npm install @microsoft/sp-application-base
```

I suspect there was a version incompatibility somewhere.